# Why isn't this displaying my info for mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql

Isn't displaying any information. Getting errors and i'm really not sure why?
Thanks.

```
    <?php

    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "insuredcars");
     if ($_POST['formcar'] == '1' || $_POST['formage'] == '18' ||  $_POST['formNCD'] ==          '0' || $_POST['formPoints'] == '0' )
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM insurance WHERE insuranceid = '1'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['insuranceprice'] . "</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
  }
 echo "</table>";

 mysql_close($con);

 ?>
```

The errors im getting:
Notice: Undefined variable: result in C: on line 8

Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\search.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined variable: con in C: on line 16

Warning: mysql_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C: on line 16

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: You're confusinf `mysqli_fetch_row` with `mysql_fetch_array`. Stick with MySQLi !

Comment: I don't know why that is not displaying any data... I mean, c'mon. We don't even know your errors!

Comment: In addition to confusing them, you're using `mysqli_fetch_row()` to attempt to grab the entire result set. As the function name implies, it just fetches ONE row. Beyond that, you are mixing functional and object-oriented mysqli. It would be good to stick with one or the other. You need a good trip through the documentation, paying careful attention to the examples. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysqli_fetch_row` fetches just one row as the function name says.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "insuredcars");
if ($_POST['formcar'] == '1' || $_POST['formage'] == '18' || $_POST['formNCD'] == '0' || $_POST['formPoints'] == '0') {    
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM insurance WHERE insuranceid = '1'");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['insuranceprice'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}

mysql_close($con);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to read other answer about using `mysqli_fetch_row` rather than `mysql_fetch_row`, but what I think you need to be careful is in this line:

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM insurance WHERE insuranceid = '1'");
```

You store the result into `$query` variable, but when you loop:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

You try to fetch `$result` variable, which is not declared here.